# Provider hosted app with Sharepoint Master page

Tags: sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app

I have a ASP.NET Web application which I would like convert as a Provider hosted app and integrate with our corporate Sharepoint 2013 portal. Layout of ASP.NET Web Applications and Sharepoint Portal is different. I need to stick on to the Sharepoint 2013 layout and branding.

Is there any way to use same Sharepoint 2013 branding on third party provider hosted app. Do I need to make it as a Sharepoint hosted app to acheive this rather than provider hosted app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes , We can apply the default SharePoint Look and feel to the Provider Hosted apps by use of SharePoint Chrome control , here we need to add this chrome control in top of the page which will inherit and apply the SharePoint Look and feel to the Provider Hosted app App parts.

```
 <!-- Chrome control placeholder 
       Options are declared inline.  -->
<div 
    id="chrome_ctrl_container"
    data-ms-control="SP.UI.Controls.Navigation"  
    data-ms-options=
        '{  
            "appHelpPageUrl" : "Help.html",
            "appIconUrl" : "siteIcon.png",
            "appTitle" : "Chrome control add-in",
            "settingsLinks" : [
                {
                    "linkUrl" : "Account.html",
                    "displayName" : "Account settings"
                },
                {
                    "linkUrl" : "Contact.html",
                    "displayName" : "Contact us"
                }
            ]
         }'>
</div>
```

Please refer these articles for more info on SharePoint Chrome Controls :

- [Give your provider-hosted add-in the SharePoint look-and-feel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt637891.aspx)
- [Use the client chrome control in SharePoint Add-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179916.aspx)